# What percentage of questions posted on WebApps SE end up being deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I see on my WebApps SE profile that I have 160 questions deleted and 343 questions not yet deleted. That means that 32% of my questions end up being deleted (160/(160+343)~=32%).

This makes me wonder: What percentage of questions posted on WebApps SE end up being deleted?

Comment: I think this might be possible to calculate from the analytics (cross checking with search) but no active users here other than mods would have access to that given the absurd rep requirement (25k). Possibly this could be answered by "A Year In Moderation" but that might only give us an estimate. By the way, the best, quickest way to figure out how many questions were deleted from this last year is for a mod to search `is:q deleted:yes created:2023`, possibly also filtering out spam posts by excluding locked posts.

Comment: @Laurel - https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1531431/percentage-of-deleted-questions-breakdown-by-year-when-created?

Comment: Related: [2023: a year in moderation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5224/7584)