# 2023: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It’s that time of the year again! As we wave goodbye to last year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here might be aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference in ensuring Stack Exchange sites remain a valuable source of high-quality content on the web.

So as we say goodbye to 2023 (and January 2024… ahem) and move into 2024, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Web Applications over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community User¹ | Community² |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 35 | 0 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 965 | 247 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 173 | 333 | 692 |
| Bounties canceled | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 1,863 | 51 | 4 |
| Comments deleted⁸ | 4,092 | 49 | 461 |
| Comments flagged | 1,747 | 10 | 161 |
| Comments undeleted | 105 | 0 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 12 | 0 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 6,585 | 0 |
| Posts deleted⁷ | 998 | 2,406 | 265 |
| Posts locked | 38 | 507 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 41 | 0 | 15 |
| Posts unlocked | 6 | 35 | 0 |
| Question flags handled⁶ | 526 | 252 | 69 |
| Questions closed | 2,334 | 1 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁶ | 131 | 14 | 676 |
| Questions merged | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 153 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 126 | 1 |
| Questions reopened | 138 | 1 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 16 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| Tags merged | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Close votes" queue | 68 | 0 | 70 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First answers" queue | 114 | 0 | 573 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First questions" queue | 160 | 0 | 822 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Late answers" queue | 161 | 0 | 419 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Low quality posts" queue | 147 | 0 | 204 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Reopen votes" queue | 89 | 0 | 51 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Suggested edits" queue | 267 | 133 | 420 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Triage" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 23 | 0 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Users destroyed⁴ | 121 | 0 | 0 |
| Users suspended³ | 16 | 52 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ This refers to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² This refers to [the membership of Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

³ The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

⁴ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁵ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁶ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). The community² can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁷ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁸ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2022: a year in moderation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/2022-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2024! ^_^

Comment: For me the worrying statistic is that the site's moderators are responsible for 80+% of question deletions.

Comment: Along with the very high number of deletions that have occurred this year; more than half of all questions asked were closed and deleted, almost all by the same three users acting unilaterally

Comment: The numbers have been updated to reflect the actual stats — there was an issue with the numbers originally posted.

Answer (score 7):

#### Data highlights:

| Site Name | Asked | AskedAndClosed | PctAskedAndClosed | AllClosed | All closed as a percentage of Asked | DuplicatesClosed | DuplicatesReopened | OTClosed | OTReopened | UnclearClosed | UnclearReopened | TooBroadClosed | TooBroadReopened | OpinionBasedClosed | OpinionBasedReopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Interpersonal Skills | 245 | 184 | 75% | 184 | 75% | 1 | 0 | 125 | 2 | 44 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| Network Engineering | 1783 | 1162 | 65% | 1169 | 66% | 59 | 2 | 933 | 7 | 149 | 18 | 8 | 1 | 20 | 0 |
| English Language and Usage | 5677 | 3618 | 64% | 4345 | 77% | 851 | 92 | 2414 | 226 | 549 | 41 | 93 | 16 | 438 | 56 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 11615 | 7301 | 63% | 8245 | 71% | 181 | 9 | 6667 | 117 | 1191 | 26 | 117 | 3 | 89 | 2 |
| Web Applications | 2378 | 1242 | **52%** | 2335 | **98%** | 283 | 16 | 945 | 24 | 1045 | 86 | 48 | 8 | 14 | 2 |
| Chemistry | 4986 | 2474 | 50% | 2508 | 50% | 256 | 4 | 970 | 16 | 1074 | 32 | 150 | 9 | 58 | 0 |
| Stack Overflow | 1489399 | 266207 | 18% | 287979 | 19% | 80073 | 2640 | 111498 | 1633 | 53724 | 941 | 31277 | 373 | 11407 | 194 |
| Music Fans | 178 | 51 | 29% | 268 | **151%** | 0 |  | 264 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 3 |  |

- Webapps is in the top 5 of all SE sites, when comparing the Percent of questions asked in 2023 that were closed in 2023. [A record 51.23%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396299/2023-a-year-in-closing) of questions asked were closed in 2023. For comparison, this was [just 19% in 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386090/2022-a-year-in-closing).
- If we take all the closed questions(not just asked in 2023) as a percentage of questions asked in 2023, a record of 98% of questions were closed. Only Music Fans SE ranks higher by number of questions closed(151%). No other sites came close to WebApps
- The stats is even more worrying, if we consider no(ZERO) questions were closed by the community, but ALL 2335(except 1) questions were closed by moderators
- No questions were reopened by the community and 139(except 1) was reopened by moderators.
- It's also worthy to note most closings are done by a moderator, while the reopenings are usually done by an another
- Compared to 2022, Posts deleted  by moderators nearly doubled, and users destroyed tripled.
- 16 users were suspended in 2023 against 0 in 2022. These show clear conflict between the moderators and the community.

---

> That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, **but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks** — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site

**This is clearly not happening in Web Applications.**

Moderators clearly did whatever they wanted or thought was right, even against all objections from community and even still continue to do so - closing, locking and deleting posts.

#### Related:

- [Reduce the reputation threshold to be allowed to cast a reopen vote on a closed question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/reduce-the-reputation-threshold-to-be-allowed-to-cast-a-reopen-vote-on-a-closed)
- [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/do-the-moderators-plan-to-close-most-questions-on-this-site)

Comment: Perhaps this will act as a wakeup call that something needs to give. Probably not though.

Comment: If moderators cared more about the site than they care about their own pride, they would've stepped down voluntarily, by now.

Comment: @TheMaster-StopWAModAbuse that is your interpretation.  Also while you may say you are interested in stopping  "WA Mod  Abuse" in practice you don't seem to do anything to stop it.

Comment: @Blindsp In practice, I tried to resolve any misunderstandings through meta. But I believe this won't work, as you/mod team deleted my discussion on mod behavior to reduce visibility/transparency on such behavior, which - disregarding the actual allegation, is a clear abuse of power. I prefer a vote of no confidence process in SE. But, without that, I can only ask, hoping you won't delete this as well. If you're interested in saving the site/community rather than defending moderators, I respectfully ask you and the moderator(s) involved to voluntarily step down, for the sake of site/community.

Comment: @TheMaster-StopWAModAbuse You had one post deleted that was extraordinarily innapropriate. If I was out of line you should escalate it to mods.  FYI You are now having your comments flagged by other community members as well.

Comment: @Blindspots Please explain why that's inappropriate. To me it is a clear abuse of power. Weren't you the one  who said [discussion on mod behavior belongs on meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/do-the-moderators-plan-to-close-most-questions-on-this-site#comment5495_4984)? Or Did you mean any defense of moderators actions is acceptable in meta, but any thing that even casts a shadow of doubt on mod integrity is not acceptable within meta? *Mod right - ok in Meta. Mod probably wrong - not ok in Meta*. Is that your stance?

Comment: @TheMaster-StopWAModAbuse 'Mod right or wrong' okay on meta. TheMaster completely out of line, not okay on site or meta. There is a universe of space between what you are comfortable posting and something that "casts a shadow of doubt" on mod actions.

Comment: @Blindspots How is "completely out of line" determined? If the allegation is "completely out of line", shouldn't the mod team respond to such grave and serious allegation with the truth, rather than  silencing it? 3 users mean consensus. Show me three users in the community with at least 500 reps in WA, who are not moderators(here or elsewhere), who agree that the deletetion is warranted or justifiable.

Comment: You already know 3 users who satisfy that criteria who objected to that deletion directly to you,  without even  having to search for it or me asking for it. And the deleted post was unanimously upvoted, by at least 6 users in 2 days, which mean they agree at minimum, transparency on the matter is required. "Completely out of line" is the interpretation of **only you** and probably that of other mods with conflict of interests.

Comment: @TheMaster we all have bias.  My goal isn't to suppress dissent, my goal is to encourage a healthy site. You are on a different timeline than the community based on when you took an active interest here. Most of use are incrementally turning the corner and rebuilding a more healthy participation from both mods and regular users. You are clearly upset but we've all had to take a step back and a breath and find a way forward. The claim that the mods bear sole responsibility for the current situation & that the community members in question always acted in good faith is an expensive one.

Comment: @Blindspots If you have old community members, who aren't moderators, who would vouch for deletion of this post as a justifiable act, show me. I can't see any one other than you claiming a moral high ground on this issue. I really don't care if members were abusive or broke so many rules I hold the position of moderator against a very high standard.  Regardless of what happened before, deleting my post is a clear abuse of moderator power and completely eroded any trust I have in you personally.

Comment: I'm also sure that those users, who, if in fact they were abusive or broke the rules - as you accuse them, were the ones who were punished, compared to mods, as you hold all the power in this relationship.  Plenty of suspensions on one side, but the mod team comes out unscathed eh? Even any accusations or dissent is hidden by forceful deletion - making them look squeaky clean. Right? Just bandaging wounds only creates stinky infections. You need to open it and expose it for real healing.

Comment: Wow even the link here pointing to the deletion(in one of the comments) is edited out. Does the truth harm you so much that you want to hide all traces of it?

Answer (score 6):

#### The Web Apps SE community has practically *no influence* over which questions get closed or reopened

I noticed some quite alarming stats: Out of **2335 questions closed** in 2023, only **1 (0.04%)** was closed by the community. Out of **139 questions reopened**, only [**1 (0.7%)** was reopened by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396375/162827). And out of 2K+ question closures, the community has only submitted **70 reviews in the close votes queue** and **51 reviews in the reopen votes queue**, resulting in *only* **1 question closed and 1 question reopened by them**. (This is even more surprising considering that Web Apps SE requires only 3 votes to close or reopen a question, unlike most SE sites, which need 5.)

This implies that **the community has practically *no influence* over which questions get closed or reopened**, a problem that was already raised in the “[Reduce the reputation threshold to be allowed to cast a reopen vote on a closed question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5185/7584)” meta post. In 2023, all 2335 question closures were done by mods, except for one, before the close vote queue reviewers had a chance to weigh in.

This contradicts [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation) (which is regarded as the canonical article on how SE moderators should moderate):

> But what do community moderators do? The short answer is, **as little as possible!**

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.

> […] moderators occasionally need to intervene. **Moderators are human exception handlers**, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not *normally* happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt

On a positive note, the "[Reduce the reputation threshold to be allowed to cast a reopen vote on a closed question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5185/7584)" meta post was recently tagged as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) by a community manager. If it gets implemented—setting “beta” reputation thresholds—then these numbers may improve and more of the community may get involved in deciding if questions are closed or reopened.

Comment: It's also important to note moderators actively  made objections against going to beta and willfully refused to add [tag:status-review] to that question. This can be easily seen as holding on to their power. TBH, the last action of deletion of moderator misconduct, [which is within meta rules according to that same moderator](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/do-the-moderators-plan-to-close-most-questions-on-this-site#comment5495_4984) makes me highly distrust any moderators here. Current Moderators here must be removed, if anyone needs any hope for this site.

Comment: @TheMaster - Or at least they could agree to address this by being less 'hands-on' with their closing and deleting. Allow the community to do more by doing less themselves. Maybe focus their energies on getting more questions fixed and reopened...

Comment: @Valorum I don't have any hope for the current moderator team. I expect them to actively oppose going to beta and double and triple down on all their actions.  Redaction of any of their actions, if any, would only come from CM's insistence on the matter.  Even then, they can agree with CMs privately and publicly - in word, but take no real action on what they agreed.